# How to dynamically query a table using node-postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am using node-postgresql to query a PostgreSQL database. How do I properly handle the optional argument *created_at*, given that I have to explicitly enumerate my paraments within the query? I thought of creating two query strings for when created_at is null or not, but this seems repetitive. I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

This is my function.

```
// Inserts a new user to the users table 
const insertUser = ({ full_name, username, email, created_at }) => {
  const q = `
    INSERT INTO users 
    (full_name, username, email)
    VALUES($1, $2, $3) 
    RETURNING *`;

  return query(q, [full_name, username, email]);
};
```

This is my table schema.

```
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(254) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: If you're doing this a lot ("this seems repetitive"), you could explore query builder libraries like [`knex`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert). These libraries generate the SQL for you, often from javascript objects' keys.

Comment: If you're only really doing this in a couple places for with just the created_at column, you might as well just go with the option you thought of which is having two different query strings.

Comment: javascript has an optional parameters(the default parameters). `param = null`, or something. build your string dynamically.